# Use ActiveX in Xamarin Studio (like adding a reference on Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

How can I add an ActiveX control to my C# solution in Xamarin Studio?!
I'm still learning C# and don't want to use Visual Studio because that would imply that I must learn both VStudio and Xamarin shortcuts, etc, because I use both OS on a daily basis.
I've just installed Xamarin, developed some quick solutions to give it a try, and haven't found this on documentation.

NOTE: This is a software that will be running on Windows only.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, ActiveX is a Microsoft concept, it does not exist in other platforms.

Comment: I develop in other languages either for Windows or Linux, so I don't want to be "attached" to Visual Studio. Mono I can use in both systems. I just need to know how to use ActiveX on Windows+Mono, if you can't help, don't start religious wars here, thank you. Also, not of your business, but I work as a sysadmin (programming is just a hobbie), self-teached, didn't went to university and married. How does this help with my question? right...

Comment: I didn't mean you were any of that, but, you know, there's plenty of such idiots around, who go around yelling `"linux and java!"` just because it's "open source", not knowing C# and .Net are 50 years ahead of all that dinosaur stuff.

Comment: I can understand that, but this was not the case :)

Comment: Sorry but I really don't see the point of this question. The answer that solved the problem is just the call to the OCX component and has nothing to do with Mono or MonoDevelop.

Comment: Ok... In Visual Studio you simply add a reference and it works, OR, you add a component and drag it to the form, and it works, so far so good right? BUT, I don't use Visual Studio, so, I wanted to know how to do it on Xamarin Studio. Now is clear ?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little more, found it was very easy.
Just use:

> aximp name_of_ocx_control

And then add it as a reference on the solution.

Comment: You can use this function, but running it on Mono outside of a Windows environment will throw errors. Take a look on my answer.

Comment: @Alexandre, I write my Pyhton code in Notepad++, what's the point? Could you tell me a valid reason to use some specific IDE just because I'm using OS X or OS Y ???? Eclipse run on both platforms, so I use Eclipse, QT IDE runs on both, so I like QT IDE, Geanny runs also on Windows and Linux, sou why should I use X or Y depending on the OS used??? I use both systems on a daily basis, I can't afford to learn all the shortcuts and stuff from Visual Studio, and THEN, learn all from Mono to use in Linux... is this so hard to understand?!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately @HighCore was right. There is no way you will be able to use ActiveX on Mono on other platforms because it is Microsoft's proprietary Framework. I mean: C# and .NET had their specifications publicly opened by Microsoft may years ago, so Mono was built using these specs. There are no specs or licenses that allows us to use ActiveX on other platforms. There are some workarounds like wine and such, but they don't play well with mono. It is very hard to make them work together.

Mono does not implement OCX controls and ActiveX outside of Windows Environment. You will have to use other technologies when running outside of windows. ActiveX controls (or OCX) are COM/COM+ components and [Mono doesn't work with it](http://www.mono-project.com/COM_Interop). Mono project developers suggest using [Mozilla's XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM) technology.